# What If document.ready won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

Every JavaScript developer sooner or later faced with case when page elements unavailable in document.onready event. It's happens because onready fired to soon, especially when most of the page parts loaded dynamically (with AJAX). I work with Drupal 7 now. Drupal does not provide Ajax callback, it's seems to be you need to write custom callbacks.

And my question is: what is the most appropriate solution for that case?

Usually I apply

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
               setTimeout(function tmr(){
               //Wait for any or task specific element will be available
                   if (jQuery('.bxslider').length) {
                            //Code here
                            do_code();
                   } else
                       setTimeout(tmr, 1000);
               }, 10);
```

Or better write a callback? Or no different at all?

Comment: Why don't you use custom callback then??? EDIT: oops sorry, looks like it is your question. So then, use callback that's the only one valid solution here

Comment: Definitely don't poll, that's just awful. Use callbacks.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can check onReady on divs. Did you try that?

Comment: @AlexBarac no you can't. All ready jquery bound events are delegated to document and are irrelevant to any element content

Comment: The best way is to use callbacks. Surely you can poll but callbacks are way more elegant and in addtition better to understand

Comment: _"Drupal does not provide Ajax callback"_. No? [Google disagrees](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=drupal+ajax&oq=drupal+ajax&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.1887j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks for advices:)
Clive, I read about [Server Side Callback](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) But I need simple client side callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach your js behaviors like this:

```
Drupal.behaviors.nameOfYourModule= {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // your code here
  }
};
```

This way your code will be executed on every request including AJAX requests.

For more information [see this blog post on the subject.](http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/drupal-behaviors-quick-how)